# Redux-persist: Unable to resolve module `react-native`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I'm trying to use `redux-persist` in my third party NPM module (which uses Typescript, if it helps). Whenever I try to use my third party module (symlinked locally) in my actual project (which is a perfectly working React Native app) I get the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native` from 
`path/to/my/3rd/party/module/node_modules/redux-persist/lib/storage/index.native.js`:
Module `react-native` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

Redux-persist states that it doesnt't require React (as it says in its README "If you are using react...", which implies it can also be used without React/React Native), why am I getting such an error?

Things I've tried:

- Add `react` (any version) as a peer dependency to my external module
- Add `react-native` (any version) as a peer dependency to my external module
- Install `react` to my external module
- Install `react-native` to my external module
- Tried `@next` version of `redux-persist` which has some changes about dependencies on React. I've also read https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/833 and https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/pull/919 though I'm not sure what to do.

I've always cleared my cache, restarted VScode and bundler etc.

Though I'm still getting the same error. How can I integrate redux-persist into my party npm package correctly (which may or may not be used with React/React Native)